# SmartFilterBar Date field display format

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to change display date format from MMM,d,y - MMM d,y to DD.MM.YYYY in SmartFilterBar date fields?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. In the Filter Bar initialization get the date control reference from smartfilterobject and set the displayformat as per the requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a proper way using annotations. I do it in the initialized event of the smart filterbar:

```
onSmartFilterBarInitialized: function (oEvent) {
            var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();

            oEvent.getSource().getAllFilterItems().forEach(function (oItem) {
                if (oItem.getControl().getMetadata()._sClassName === "sap.m.DatePicker") {
                    oItem.getControl().setDisplayFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                }
            }.bind(this));

        }
    });
```